# Jmeter Regular Expression Extractor to extract an input value

Tags: regex, xpath, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter's Regular Expression Extractor. For an HTTP Request, I am getting an HTML Response. I want to extract an e-mail address which is a hidden value in that response for use in the subsequent request.

The string is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="login" id="login" value="abs12.test@test.com" >
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 5):

You may also maybe like more effective [XPath Extractor](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor), used the same way as RegEx Extractor.
XPath query will look like:

```
//input[@type='hidden'][@name='login']/@value
```

and extractor itself:

[image: xpath extractor]

Answer (score 1):

This site has great tutorials on how to perl regex's: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

I would also recommend getting the tool "Regex Coach" to help you write - it searches for your string in real time.

But, your regex will look something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="login" id="login" value="(.+?)" >
```

You want to make sure you include the (), as that is the part JMeter will store into your variable.

Answer (score 1):

Regexp as following

```
id="login" value="(.*)"
```

Comment: Please give an explain why this answers the question. Code-only answers often gets closed.