# how can i extract a hidden value passed through an http request in jmeter and post it in next sampler

Tags: testing, jmeter

I see the otp passed like this. I need to extract the OTP and post it in the OTP field request
`<input type="hidden" name="CCus" value="TesSS4550379362465">
<input type="hidden" name="OTPHidden" value="Z5oJYn">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmeter Regular Expression Extractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647239/jmeter-regular-expression-extractor)

Comment: It has been answered in SO many times. just search / google it.

Answer (score 4):

There are several options:

1. Using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) like:

   - Reference Name: any variable name, i.e. `OTP`
   - Regular Expression: `<input type="hidden" name="OTPHidden" value="(.+?)">`
   - Template: `$1$`
2. Using [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) like:

   - Use Tidy - `check`. It might not be required if your response is XML/XHTML-compliant
   - Reference Name: `OTP`
   - XPath query: `//input[@name='OTPHidden']/@value`
3. [Using CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) like:

   - Reference Name: `OTP`
   - CSS/JQuery Expression: `input[name=OTPHidden]`
   - Attribute: `value`

In all cases refer the extracted value as `${OTP}` in the next request.

---

In regards to which option to choose:

- If your markup doesn't change frequently and the input always comes in one line -  go for Regular Expressions
- If your page has complex DOM and not very complex styles - go for CSS/JQuery
- If there are many styles but DOM is relatively simple - use XPath

Comment: i cannot get the desired output and its showing error in aspx page like ......./error1/?aspxerrorpath=/signupconfirmation/ and found no otp is passed. I tried using regular expression. I gave the extractor in the same request where is need to pass the otp,the hidden things are in that request

Comment: I do tried all 3, but default value which i have given is posted in the request, but not that particular OTP. I gave the extractors in the get request just before that post request.but i am unable to get the correct hidden otp value